# connect: Network is uinreachable

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have a problem with my network connection. When I tried to `ping 8.8.8.8` I get an error that  `"Network is unreachable"`. I tried to restart `dhclient` for *eth0* but did not help. It is weird, that it don't show any message. When I tried to restart networking (`/etc/init.d/networking restart` ) there is not show any message. I don't have much skill with Linux so please help me :))

this is content of /etc/network/interfaces

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: reedit your question by posting the content of this file: `/etc/networking/interfaces`

Comment: Are your using a server or a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines to your /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

These two lines are to set up the eth0 interface as dhcp. According to OP's question, he mentioned "dhclient" so I think this is what he want's.

After you are done with that save the files and run the following :

if you are on 13.10 or before this should restart your networking:

```
$ sudo service networking restart
```

If on 14.04 the above may not work so try this

```
$ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

to pull the eth0 interface down and then restart it with the changes in the above networking file.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please describe what the described steps do? [Code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for shell commands would be nice as well.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFoerster. I made the changes. New here and tried answering from the stack exchange app for android. Couldn't figure out how to format the code on that.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was an app, but then again I have no smartphone anyway.